# Every non-negative multivariate polynomial has degree even?

Tags: polynomials

Is it true that every non-negative multivariate polynomial with $n$ variable on $\mathbb R$ has even degree?

By degree of polynomial I mean greatest sum of powers of variables for each monomial.

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, suppose any variable $y$ appears to a greatest power $m$ which is odd (holding all other variables constant such that the coefficient of $y^m$ is nonzero). Then by sending $y$ to $-\infty$, we can make the expression become as negative as we wish.

Comment: Perhaps we have many monomials which has $y^m$ and all have same degree!

Comment: @Nothing Substitute constants for all the other variables, such that the remaining $y^m$ term is nonzero.

Comment: @PatrickStevens I don't think I fully understood your argument. How would you choose the variable $y$ if the polynomial is $p(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x_1 x_2 x_3 + x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2$?