# Every non-negative multivariate polynomial has even degree and the highest degree term has positive coefficient?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Part of my question has been asked before ([Every non-negative multivariate polynomial has degree even?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2706393/every-non-negative-multivariate-polynomial-has-degree-even)) but the proof there is not very satisfactory. The other part of my question involves proving (or disproving) that the highest-degree term, say $ c\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{a_i}$ (where we know $\sum_i a_i$ is even), must have its coefficient $c > 0$.

Are these two conditions (i.e., the polynomial having even degree and its highest degree term having positive coefficient) also sufficient for guaranteeing the polynomial is bounded from below?

Answer (score 1):

Let $R(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ be our polynomial, $P(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ be a polynomial consisting of highest degree monomials from $R$ (it's homogeneous polynomial of odd degree) and $Q = R - P$.

We need that any polynomial with non-zero coefficients is non zero in at least one point. We can prove it by induction by number of variables: non-zero polynomials of $1$ variable have finite number of zeros; if polynomial of $n + 1$ variables is zero everywhere, then coefficients of any degree of the first variable are identically zero as polynomials of rest $n$ variables.

So for some $a_i$, $P(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n) \neq 0$. Thus $P(a_1 t, a_2 t, \ldots, a_n t)$ is non-zero homogeneous polynomial of one variable of odd degree. Then $R(a_1 t, \ldots, a_n t)$ is polynomial of odd degree - then it is negative at some point $t_0$, and so $R$ is negative at $a_1 t_0, a_2 t_0, \ldots, a_n t_0$.

For the second part - if highest degree term is unique and polynomial is positive - highest degree coefficient should be positive (otherwise polynomial will approach $-\infty$ as variables grow). It it's non unique - some coefficients can be negative. Take, for example, polynomial $(x - y)^2 + 1$.

Having even degree and all highest degree coefficients positive isn't enough for polynomial to be bounded: take, for example, $x^2 - y$.